# Why can't we use new ClassName() like we use in java,instead of using new ClassName?

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, upcasting

I have wondered that both c++ and java using oops concepts but the syntaxes are quite different.

I found that java uses new ClassName() to get a reference to the heap but getting the same reference to the heap why the c++ uses new ClassName.

```
 #include<iostream>
 using namespace std;

class Bike
{
public:
    virtual  void run()
    {
        cout << "running";
    }
};

class Splender :public Bike
{
public:
    void run()
    {
        cout << "running safely with 60km";
    }
};

int main()
{
    Bike &obj = new Splender();//error but reason?
    obj.run();
}
```

ERROR:
 invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'Bike&' from an rvalue of type 'Splender*'

Comment: Read a C++ textbook, C++ is not Java

Comment: If you don't know whey `Bike &obj=new Splender();` is an error, it's time to get back to [a good text book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: The error message says the reason.

Comment: The question is based on false premise. Yes, we **can** use `new ClassName()` in C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things. One: Operator new returns a pointer, not a reference, to an object instance. So use `Bike* obj = new Splender();`

Two: Do not get cute and try `Bike& obj = *new Splender();` because new can return `nullptr` in a low memory situation and if you dereference it, your program will crash at that point. (And you are forced to use the ugly `delete *obj;` to clean up this object as user4581301 points out in the comments.)

Oh, and `using namespace std` is a bad practice. It won't kill you to add `std::` in the places you use the standard library.

Comment: "your program will crash at that point." Not necessarily. This be Undefined Behaviour. It could look like it worked or rain unicorns.

Comment: Dereferencing null in every C++ implementation I've ever used (including one running on MVS on an IBM Mainframe) causes a crash (or ABEND on MVS). There are times when the strict definition of Undefined Behavior can step aside for practice real-world experience.

Comment: Gotta give you that. Can't remember the last time I didn't crash over a null. Worth noting that it's more likely `new` will `throw` or die trying to `throw` than return a `nullptr`.

Comment: Well, in a modern compiler, throwing is more likely. But in extreme low memory situations, you can still get null. Also, there are switches on most compilers to disable exceptions (both globally and specifically inside `new`.)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

class Bike {
public:
    virtual void run() {
        std::cout << "running";
    }
    virtual ~Bike() {}
};

class Splender: public Bike {
public:
    void run() override {
        std::cout << "running safely with 60km";
    }
};

int main() {
    Bike *obj = new Splender(); // new returns a pointer to a dynamically allocated object
    obj->run();
    delete obj;
}
```

which displays:

`running safely with 60km`

Comment: I don't see what you are talking about ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes we think doing the right thing.
You make a bit confusion. Try:

```
Bike *obj=new Splender();
```